# Examples of 'Antonymous' in publication?

Tags: word-usage

It occurred to me a few years ago that Antonymous ought be a legitimate English word, built just as is Synonymous, and was pleased to find it listed in Unabridged Editions of several dictionaries, such as the Merriam-Webster and Oxford.

However, I've yet to come across it anywhere aside from the aforementioned entries and similar entries on Google. Does anyone know of ANY examples of its usage in publication?

Search Engine Queries naturally return results akin to "Antonyms + [Search Terms in addition to 'Antonymous']" i.e. "Antonyms of Publish / Publication / Use / Usage / Print / et cetera", which is less than helpful, even if technically what I requested.

Comment: Hello, Brielle. I get plenty of hits in a Google search for 'antonymous'. Admittedly, a lot of the early ones are 'mention' (eg dictionary definitions) rather than 'use' examples, but there are many examples to be found later.

Comment: books.google.com is also a good source

Answer (score 2):

This word occurs in articles on Google Scholar with respect to adjectives.

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=antonymous&btnG=